# How to keep AVPlayer video playing when app goes background

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, avplayer

I'm trying to keep the video in AVPlayer playing when app goes background, but it always stops. I use Swift. I've found a lot of examples, but nothing works.

I've turned on "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay" in Info.plist and added this code to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}
catch {
    /*Error*/
}
```

What is the proper way to keep video playing?

Comment: Have you added the AudioToolbox framework? I think you may also need AVFoundation

Comment: Also in the project's settings under Capabilities, try enabling Background Modes and checking the box for "Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture"

Comment: @MattLeFleur Yes, I've added both frameworks and enabled "Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture".

Comment: @user3785463 did you solve this?

Comment: @user3785463 did you ever solve this issue?